# Which components of this Kia Sorento are the circled?

Tags: kia, automotive-design

[image]

I would like to know what these components are?

Comment: What year is the car?

Answer (score 0):

The topmost circle looks like the knock sensor,
while the other two look like connectors to components - not sure which ones. A photo prior to you removing them may help unless they were removed by someone else.

The knock sensor is designed to detect "knocking" or pre-detonation in a cylinder due to extreeme engine conditions. When that happens the ecu will reduce the timing or fuel delivery so that damage does not occur to the engine. Excessive pre-detonation for long periods will severely damage an engine.

Comment: What’s the function? I read that it detects knocks but have no idea what that is

Comment: @KwakuE.Biney edited my answer, but you did not ask that in your original question.

Comment: @Moab I don’t know, perhaps ask the OP.

Comment: oops, wrong comment section.